# .mp3, .mp4 , .wmv and .tif files types are not getting crawled in SharePoint 2010

Tags: search, search-results

Hi I am working on SharePoint 2010 and I have added mp3, mp4, wmv, and tif file types in search service application and have done full crawl. But I am unable to pull the results in the site. Do i need to do any change or check anything in regards to these file types. I have already checked my blocked file types and these are not included. Previously I have few file types and ran full crawl and they are pulling in my site while I am searching. Only problem with the above file types. Could some one suggest me what is blocking these results and how to overcome this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In 2010, depending on the size of the files, you had to increase the download size for the Search Service. The default was 16MB. You should check your crawl logs and ensure that this is the issue.

```
$s = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$s.GetProperty("MaxDownloadSize")
$s.SetProperty("MaxDownloadSize",25)
$s.Update()
```

Then restart the service:

```
Restart-Service osearch14
```

Comment: Hi Matthew..Thanks for your time and the environment I am testing here is dev,so I have only 3 kb files added to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the glitch I found
 checked my DOCICON.XML file in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML in which these files are not included. I have added

```
 <Mapping Key="mp3" Value="icwmv.gif" OpenControl=""/>
 <Mapping Key="mp4" Value="icwmv.gif" OpenControl=""/>
 <Mapping Key="wmv" Value="icwmv.gif" OpenControl=""/>
```

and ran full crawl and did IISRESET then everything working fine now.

Comment: Odd, that file has nothing to do with crawling. It only controls the presentation of the icons. Maybe you had not run a full crawl previously?

Comment: i had run full crawl Matt, and yes its odd that it pulled the results after adding icons. But you might be knowing most of the times SP does odd things and could not figure out what the glitch is!Thanks again Matt for a good insight on the issue.